# Why is my csv file changed when downloaded?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a problem while displayinh a .csv file a friend of mine sent to me online. Ineed, it used to be much more simpler tnat the screenshot below.
What can I do to retrieve the original file ?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you need to open the file using `;` as a delimiter not `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear to be a (csv) **comma** separated file; rather it appears to be a semicolon separated file. And it also appears that there are some issues with rows 42 and below -- perhaps there were commas there within the text.

In any event

1. Download the file onto your computer. (Do **NOT** Open the file with Excel)
2. Change the file type suffix to `.txt`.  You may have to enable the feature to show file name extensions in File Explorer ( ► View ► Show/Hide ► File name extensions)

   - This may or may not be necessary, but Excel has some built-in transformations it will do with csv files, that may be undesireable in this case.
3. In Excel, navigate to Data ► Get External Data ► From Text

[image]

Now select your file from the dialog box for Import. This will open the Text import wizard.

You can now select the delimiter (probably a semi-colon) and you can also define the date format for your date column (e.g: DMY) as well as defining other columns as Text or General.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the first column
2. Go to *Data > Text to Columns*. This starts a wizard.

[image]

3. Click *Delimited > Next*.

[image]

4. Check *semicolon* and clear the rest of the boxes. You can see a preview of your data in the Data preview window and click *Next*.
5. Now you can pick the format for your new columns, or you can let Excel do it for you.
6. Click *Finish*.